# SharePoint 2013 discussion board list issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

we are using an OOTb discussion board list . and when we click on the unanswered tab it gives the error with corelation ID:

[image: gives the error with corelation ID]

logs are

```
0x62F4  SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium      Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|adcouncil\umofarmacc, ClaimsCount=28 5c43589d-b0c1-30d1-cd87-5bd796a2c343
01/24/2016 09:08:55.45  w3wp.exe (0x1B48)                           0x62F4  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/departments/it    5c43589d-b0c1-30d1-cd87-5bd796a2c343
01/24/2016 09:08:55.46  w3wp.exe (0x1B48)                           0x62F4  SharePoint Foundation           Performance                     ki9i    High        Query needs to have a WHERE clause with an NVP field if UseNvpForOrderBy is TRUE.   5c43589d-b0c1-30d1-cd87-5bd796a2c343
01/24/2016 09:08:55.46  w3wp.exe (0x1B48)                           0x62F4  SharePoint Foundation           Health                          46ri    High        Throttled:Big list slow query. List item query elapsed time: 0 milliseconds, Additional data (if available): Query HRESULT: 80070024 List internal name, flags, and URL: {7D30631C-AB31-4943-929D-B89AE6E20035}, flags=0x0020000820c01000, URL="http://srumos08/departments/it/_layouts/15/inplview.aspx?List={7D30631C-AB31-4943-929D-B89AE6E20035}&View={28C8175B-94A9-4EB8-A036-AF5C08D50092}&ViewCount=4&IsXslView=TRUE&IsCSR=TRUE&HasOverrideSelectCommand=TRUE&FolderCTID=0x012002001D0510CE0262EB46B96E5EA2E3FBBF3F" Current User: 1073741823 Query XML: "<Query><OrderBy UseIndexForOrderBy="TRUE" Override="TRUE"/><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="IsAnswered"/><Value Type="Integer">0</Value></Eq></Where></Query>" SQL Query: "N/A"  5c43589d-b0c1-30d1-cd87-5bd796a2c343
01/24/2016 09:08:55.46  w3wp.exe (0x1B48)                           0x62F4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         xxpm    High        Unable to execute query: Error 0x80070585   5c43589d-b0c1-30d1-cd87-5bd796a2c343
01/24/2016 09:08:55.46  w3wp.exe (0x1B48)                           0x62F4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8e2s    Medium      Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070585  5c43589d-b0c1-30d1-cd87-5bd796a2c343
01/24/2016 09:08:55.46  w3wp.exe (0x1B48)                           0x62F4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         72k4    Medium      <nativehr>0x80070585</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>  5c43589d-b0c1-30d1-cd87-5bd796a2c343
01/24/2016 09:08:55.46  w3wp.exe (0x1B48)                           0x62F4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8kh7    High        <nativehr>0x80070585</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>  5c43589d-b0c1-30d1-cd87-5bd796a2c343
01/24/2016 09:08:55.46  w3wp.exe (0x1B48)                           0x62F4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         aix9j   High        SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2: UserPrincipalName=i:0).w|s-1-5-21-2165195311-2691588097-3176437156-3628, AppPrincipalName= ,pSqlClient=<null> ,bstrUrl=http://srumos08/departments/it ,bstrListName={7D30631C-AB31-4943-929D-B89AE6E20035} ,bstrViewName=<null> ,bstrViewXml=<View><Query><OrderBy UseIndexForOrderBy="TRUE" Override="TRUE"/><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="IsAnswered"/><Value Type="Integer">0</Value></Eq></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="ID"/><FieldRef Name="PermMask"/><FieldRef Name="Created"/><FieldRef Name="Modified"/><FieldRef Name="Title"/><Field ,fSafeArrayFlags=SAFEARRAYFLAG_AUTOHYPERLINK  5c43589d-b0c1-30d1-cd87-5bd7.
```

there are no any unexpected or critical exception coming . And there are no items in the unanswered questions tab. the list is not big , it just has 3-4 items in it . dont know whats happening

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: question is , i m getting error when i click on the Unanswered Questions tab . just a correlation ID . and when i search through that ID , there are no any critical logs logging for it . and there is discussion board list in other sites as well . but the error is coming only in one site not in the others. got my point ?

Answer (score 0):

What permission level of the account you are using? Try to use another user with higher permission to compare the result.

And what authentication type you are using in this site? If ADFS has been configured, check the following link to see if this is the case:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79864/sharepoint-2013-adfs-login-local-token-cache-always-expired

Here are some more troubleshooting you can try:

Check if the standard site features are enabled in this issued site.

Then check if there are any customized solution in this site, sometimes they can cause conplicts.

Also check the name of your discussion board is there are any special characters.

Reset IIS and compare the result.

For more details, you can refer to the link below:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74fd83cb-e8f8-4b20-acd9-ed0b16059e9b/discussion-board-error?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: i have checked the above links , and i still have problems with the list .i am also getting : 01/27/2016 14:30:02.94  w3wp.exe (0x2030)                        0x2F68 SharePoint Foundation          Web Parts                      89a1 High     Error while executing web part: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:

Answer (score 0):

How many items does your discussion list contain? In the error there is something like 'big list slow query' which might mean that you are over the resource throttling limit (max items in a list to ensure performance in one view). By default it's 5000 i think... Do you have more than 5000 items in your list?

Comment: no @Verthosa , we hardly have 3 to 4 items in it . in the chrome i noticed if i check the option 'Prevent this page from creating dialogs' then it doesnt give any error . But in IE i dont have the checkbox in the error just the message box with corelation ID.